# Correct way of detecting preference changes in a live wallpaper?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, live-wallpaper, preferenceactivity

I created a live wallpaper with a preference activity. Unfortunately, any time the user changes a setting the onSharedPreferenceChangeListener gets called. The listener calls some routines that are somewhat CPU intensive (reinitialize a large mesh) so it makes the preference activity sluggish. How can I call the listener only when the user exits the preference activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use onPause or onDestroy in your preferenceActivity to calculate your large mesh. Seems you just want to recalculate on changes on any attribute, so just set a flag in onPreferencesChanged and do your maths when activity is closed and your going back to liveWallpaper-View.

Another way would be to start your calculation in a parallel thread, to let the preferenceActivity act as normal.

Comment: yeah that's what I ended up doing. I don't know if that's the "android" way but it's a workaround that works

Answer (score 2):

Get an instance of a `SharedPreferences` object with:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Then register a `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`

I usually have my `Engine` class implement the `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` interface so I simply invoke inside the constructor of my `Engine`:

```
mPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

Then simply implement the `onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key)` method in your `Engine` class.

You could also implement a separate class to act as the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` if you like.

Comment: No, that's what I already do. The problem is that onSharedPreferences() gets called repeatedly with each preference change. I want it called *once*, preferably when the preference activity exits.